# What kind of interest rate is used on treasury bills?

Tags: united-states, interest-rate, compound-interest, treasury

Let me use an example.

If we say the yield to maturity of 1 month treasury bill is 2.414% now, what exactly does it mean?

In [actuarial notations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actuarial_notation), this number can mean effective interest rate (APY), nominal interest rate convertible m times, force of interest (continuously compounding), and many others.

What kinds of interest rate are we referring to when quoting treasury rate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convention for the *coupon* of treasury bills (and most other bonds) is to show the *annualized* uncompounded interest rate. So if the stated coupon for a 1-month bill is 2.414%, that means it pays a 2.414%/12 = 0.2012% coupon.

If 2.414% is the  *yield*, then it's a different story. The yield of a bond is the return you get *relative to what you pay for the bond*. It's much more complicated, but the main difference is that the calculation *does* include compounding, unlike the coupon rate.

> If we say the yield to maturity of 1 month treasury bill is 2.414% now, what exactly does it mean?

Well you also need to know the coupon rate and daycount convention, but *roughly* it means that your return over 1 month (amount received/amount paid) is `1.02424^1/12`, so back-calculating for price would mean

```
P = (1+i*1/12)/(1.02414^1/12)
```

where i is the stated coupon rate, which is divided by 12 since you are only entitled to one month of interest.

Comment: Does yield to maturity uses the same convention? If the duration is less than 6 months how are things computed (If a zero coupon treasury bill is 1 month before maturity and has face value $1000 with yield 2.414%, what's the market value now?)

Comment: @gamma I just added that. yield _does_ take compounding into effect, and is a more complicated calculation.

Comment: OK thank you I've also edited the question to clarify

Comment: So that number is APY (according to the answer you're given here)?

Comment: @gamma it's probably YTM (yield to maturity).

Comment: This description is confusing me because Treasury Bills don't have coupons.

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. you're right - I was answering more in the context of notes that pay coupons. with bills the YTM would just be a function of the purchase price and time to maturity.